Handling the WebSocketSession close event if initialization was not successful
I use spring-graphql 1.3.1 as part of spring-boot-starter-graphql.
I want to create a GraphQL subscription to the server which does not belong to me (means I can not do anything on server side to solve my issue).
This is how I create subscription and handle events
        WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient(HttpClient.create(),
                () -> WebsocketClientSpec.builder().maxFramePayloadLength(256 * 1024));

        String url = configs.getWsUrl();
        WebSocketGraphQlClient graphQlClient = WebSocketGraphQlClient
                .builder(url, client)
                .keepAlive(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .interceptor(new GraphQlClientInterceptor(configs))
                .build();

        Flux<ClientGraphQlResponse> clientGraphQlResponseFlux = graphQlClient
                .document(getQuery(configs))
                .executeSubscription();

        AtomicReference<String> offset = new AtomicReference<>(configs.getOffset());
        Disposable disposable = clientGraphQlResponseFlux
                .map(data -> data.toEntity(BusinessEvent.class))
                .doOnError(error -> {
                    log.error("Error in subscription");
                })
                .subscribe(message -> {
                    //business logic
                });


And this is how I send Auth token - as part of connection_init payload in the GraphQlClientInterceptor
public class GraphQlClientInterceptor implements WebSocketGraphQlClientInterceptor {

    private final SubscriptionManagement configs;

    /**
     * Create payload property data. Connection Init is in following format
     * <pre>
     * {
     *   "id": "{GUID}"
     *   "type": "connection_init",
     *   "payload": {
     *     "Authorization": "Bearer {OAUTH TOKEN}
     *     "x-app-key": "{APPLICATION KEY}"
     *   }
     * }<pre/>
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Object> connectionInitPayload() {
        Map<String, String> payload = Map.of(
                "x-app-key", configs.getAppKey(),
                "Authorization", configs.getAuthorization()
        );
        return Mono.just(payload);
    }
}


In general it works fine - I'm able to connect to the server and process messages. Once some errors occurs I'm able to handle them as well.
But when I started testing flow with invalid auth credentials - the error was not throw to my handler (means doOnError()). I see just log message like this -

"GraphQlSession over ReactorNettyWebSocketSession[id=2127633d,
uri=wss://my-url] disconnected with CloseStatus[code=4401,
reason=Unauthorised - Invalid credentials]".

Based on my investigation - WebSocketGraphQlTransport tries to terminate request. But at the time when connection_init payload send (and was rejected because of invalid auth token) there no connection yet. Similar issue happens when connection timeout error occurs. In my understanding the issue is - when error occurs on the connection_init phase I do not receive any Errors in the Flux.
I'm looking a way to be able to handle any issues that occurs during subscription lifecycle. I would appreciate any help here.
